# Instagram API Apps Limit

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We deliver social local media products which listen to several different hashtags on Instagram, among others. I'm very much in fear of hitting their API limits, and can't find how to handle many large projects with an Instagram API account.

Right now, I have 5 different clients on Instagram (the maximum), but the problem is if I have 40 projects with 40 separate hashtags each then that is 1600 different hashtags to listen to. If I check each hashtag for new updates every 5 minutes, at 1 API request per hashtag I would hit the hourly limit of the API extremely fast.

How does Instagram want one to handle this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

[Instagram's recommendation](https://instagram.com/developer/limits/) is to authenticate users and use the <kbd>OAuth</kbd> per endpoint, since **the rate limit for authenticated calls scales as you grow the amount of people using your app**.

Why or how it will scale is, the Rate Limit for Authenticated users is per hour per token. So if you have `50` authenticated users, you can make `50 x 5000 = 250,000` API calls before you hit the limit.

From their [API Limits Documentation Page](https://instagram.com/developer/limits/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we don't actually have any users logging in. We just want to fetch the content and show it on our platform.

Comment: Then those are the limits you have to deal with :)

Comment: How is possible to let each user make a request from a single machine? I mean I have a JavaEE server, which checks something with the Instagram API, how Can I do to overcome the rate limit?